# strlen gives segmentation fault in loop

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, strlen

on a hackerrank problem i need to get the no of elements in string,
how to get strlen to work without giving segmentation fault

already searched and got similar results that includes telling to put "\0"
at the end of string but idk how it works

```
int main() {

    int n,c;
    char s[1024];
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%s", s);
        c=strlen(s);
        for(int j=0;j<c;j+=2)
        {
            printf("%s",s[j]);
        }
        printf(" ");
        for(int k=1;k<c;k+=2)
        {
            printf("%s",s[k]);
        }

    }


    return 0;
}
```

please explain me how to use strlen or any other alternative like isspace in this or a code to count the characters

Comment: It is not strlen that gives the segmentation fault. Use  printf("%s",&s[j]); and printf("%s",&s[k]) Or printf("%s",s + j); and printf("%s",s + k); If you want to output just one character then use the format specifier %c. For example printf("%c",s[j]);

Comment: I'd recommend not even using `scanf()` to read strings from stdin. Instead, better use `fgets()`.

Comment: This should be `scanf("%1023s", s);`.

Comment: `scanf` is a crutch you need to stop using as soon as possible. I've seen way too many snippets of C code here where the problem is working around limitations of that tool. You also need to pay attention to return codes. `scanf` can return an error condition, which you completely ignore. You should also compile with all warnings turned on, `-Wall`, to be informed of any potential issues you may not be aware of.

Comment: @tadman Its error return is 0, in case anybody was wondering. That means that no format specifiers were matched.

Comment: @JL2210 On what input data?

Comment: @mohamedArshad Did you want to print only half of the strings or print parts of the string more than once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two lines:

```
printf("%s",s[j]);
...
printf("%s",s[k]);
```

are printing characters as strings. Instead, do this:

```
printf("%c",s[j]);
...
printf("%c",s[k]);
```

---

Also, to avoid buffer overflows, you should do this:

```
scanf("%1023s", s);
```

instead of this:

```
scanf("%s", s);
```

---

Full code with fixes (including declaring `main` as `int main(void)`):

```
int main(void) {
    int n,c;
    char s[1024];
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%1023s", s);
        c=strlen(s);
        for(int j=0;j<c;j+=2)
        {
            printf("%s", &s[j]);
        }
        printf(" ");
        for(int k=1;k<c;k+=2)
        {
            printf("%s", &s[k]);
        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```